# In Rails model, can we not save an item if the table doesn't exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, callback

I have several databases that use the `Records` model. In this model's `after_save` callback, I am creating a new row in `LogTable`. I have something like:

```
class Records < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :record_to_log
  def record_to_log
    new_log = LogTable.new
    new_log.keyword = "keyword"
    new_log.save
  end
end
```

But not all my databases have the `LogTable` table. I am getting an error that says the `LogTable` doesn't exist. How do I prevent this error, and is there a way to abort save if the table doesn't exist in a particular database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if the table exists by

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists? 'log_table'
```

The callback can be modified like

```
after_save :record_to_log, :if => ActiveRecord::Base.connection.table_exists?('log_table')
```